# Accessing server running inside virtual machine

Tags: web-server, virtual-machines

I am running Ubuntu on a OS X, using Parallels and Ubuntu is running a web server on port 8080. I want to test the development outside the virtual machine. But when I try the ip address of the Ubuntu virtual machine, it redirects itself to localhost and fails.

Any advice on how to access the web server running inside the virtual machine, outside of it.

Answer (score 3):

Set the network mode to "bridged" so the VM gets an address on the same network as the host.

Comment: Thanks. Problem was in my Glassfish server configuration, which was forcing access through localhost only, which I fixed by explicitly mentioning IP address. But your explanation helped me in understanding available networking modes for Parallels.